# awk to fill from previous value then delete

Tags: awk

Would like to consider the line if the second column `( $2=="")`is null then print the value as `$1` and rest of the lines till the next second column is null `($2=="")`.
Then need to `delete` all the rows where second column is empty `( $2=="")`

file.csv

```
Name_Subject,Marks,Desc,Details
Adam,,,
English,10,xxx,xxx
Maths,20,yyy,yyy
Benn,,,
English,10,xxx,xxx
Maths,20,yyy,yyy
Science,30,zzz,zzz
Zak,,,
English,10,xxx,xxx
Maths,20,yyy,yyy
```

output.csv

```
Name,Subject,Marks,Desc,Details
Adam,English,10,xxx,xxx
Adam,Maths,20,yyy,yyy
Benn,English,10,xxx,xxx
Benn,Maths,20,yyy,yyy
Benn,Science,30,zzz,zzz
Zak,English,10,xxx,xxx
Zak,Maths,20,yyy,yyy
```

I have tried like below command without success ...

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{print; next} {if($2 == ""){$2=A}} {A=$2} 1' file.csv
```

**Edit#1**

Actual file contains , some of the rows entire line is empty in between the data. For this instance , it is filling the empty value but like to capture the previous non-empty value.

file.csv

```
Name_Subject,Marks,Desc,Details
Adam,,,
English,10,xxx,xxx
Maths,20,yyy,yyy
Benn,,,
English,10,xxx,xxx
Maths,20,yyy,yyy
Science,30,zzz,zzz
,,,
,,,
History,40,zzz,zzz
Zak,,,
English,10,xxx,xxx
Maths,20,yyy,yyy
```

Output#1

```
Name,Subject,Marks,Desc,Details
Adam,English,10,xxx,xxx
Adam,Maths,20,yyy,yyy
Benn,English,10,xxx,xxx
Benn,Maths,20,yyy,yyy
Benn,Science,30,zzz,zzz
,History,40,zzz,zzz
Zak,English,10,xxx,xxx
Zak,Maths,20,yyy,yyy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN  { FS=OFS="," }
    NR==1  { split($1,f,/_/); name=f[1]; $1=f[2] }
    $2=="" { name=$1; next }
    { print name, $0 }
' file
Name,Subject,Marks,Desc,Details
Adam,English,10,xxx,xxx
Adam,Maths,20,yyy,yyy
Benn,English,10,xxx,xxx
Benn,Maths,20,yyy,yyy
Benn,Science,30,zzz,zzz
Zak,English,10,xxx,xxx
Zak,Maths,20,yyy,yyy
```

Comment: You're thinking about it backwards (i.e. negatively). Don't think about what you need to delete, think about what you need to print. Now look at it again and see if it makes more sense.

Comment: Ed Morton, while executing the command in the actual file , found there are entire row is empty line, please see the Edit#1 and kindly advise

Comment: Just add `$1==""{next}` up front.

Comment: Ed Morton, Superb , Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Short **awk** approach:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1;$1==""{next}NR>1 && $2==""{ f=$1; next }f{ print f,$0 }' OFS=',' file
```

The output:

```
Name_Subject,Marks,Desc,Details
Adam,English,10,xxx,xxx
Adam,Maths,20,yyy,yyy
Benn,English,10,xxx,xxx
Benn,Maths,20,yyy,yyy
Benn,Science,30,zzz,zzz
Benn,History,40,zzz,zzz
Zak,English,10,xxx,xxx
Zak,Maths,20,yyy,yyy
```

Comment: RomanPerekhrest , Thanks a ton for your support.while executing the command in the actual file , found there are entire row is empty line, please see the Edit#1 and kindly advise